# Home electricity power not working

Tags: electrical-panel

I just replaced my electric panel box ; my light are working but I can’t get my dryer; washer machine or garbage disposal to power up

Comment: Did you reset any GFCI  outlets/breakers?

Comment: Wow, that's a big one.  We're going to need a lot more information in order to be of any *material* help. Who did the work?  What was done? Can you post photos?  [edit] your question to add detail.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the new panel, and identify which breakers/circuits in it do not work?

Comment: Do you have 240v to the panel? We really need more info or the question will be closed.

Comment: This seems to go well beyond "Home Improvement"...Insufficient information to make a decision involving safety Should this question be removed?